# Passing a List as Function Argument R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a function that retrieves game data from ESPN. It takes one argument. Need a way to create a list of game ids that the function can loop over. We will call the name of the function "get_data".

The function works for a single game

```
get_data(1000001)
```

But if I have multiple games stored in a list... how can I loop over them in one call?

```
game_ids <- c("1000001", "1000002", "1000003")


get_data(game_ids)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not vectorized, `Vectorize` it  and apply on a vector of 'ids' with length >= 1

```
Vectorize(get_data)(game_ids)
```

---

Or another option is to loop over the `vector` and apply the function individually

```
lst1 <- lapply(game_ids, function(x) get_data(x))
```